# DataSet, DataAdapter, no dataTable Primary key

Tags: vb.net, oledb

Ok so I'm having this:

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Articles"
dAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection)
dSet = New DataSet("tempDatatable")

With connection
    .Open()
    dAdapter.Fill(dSet, "Articles_table")
    .Close()
End With

With DataGridView1
    .DataSource = dSet
    .DataMember = "Articles_table"
End With
```

And I wonder if there is any possible way to define the first column as the primary key. I've looked around but everyone is using a manual datatable to fill up the datagrid. Since I'm using a dataBase I don't know how to set a primary key from there. I need some help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a primary key to your data table using something like this:

```
var table = dSet.Tables["Articles_table"];
table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { table.Columns[0] };
```

Sorry, just realised the question was tagged with vb.net, not c#. VB.net would be:

```
Dim table = dSet.Tables("Articles_table")
table.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {table.Columns(0)}
```

Comment: In answer to your other question, you need to add this after the table is filled, since you are using the `SqlDataAdapter.Fill` method to define your dataset, before you fill your data the table has no columns. To do it before you can use the `MissingSchemaAction` option to use the databases Metadata to add the key to your table.

Comment: @GarethD I always prefer `new[] { table.Columns[0] }` style when initializing an array. Love type inference magic..

Comment: Since he is filling a table from database via DataAdapter it is probably better to let the database give the primary key informations. That will also prevent problems if the primary key columns(s) will change or be renamed in future. Therefore add the DataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction approach to the answer, otherwise its incomplete.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Re: using MissingSchemaAction I agree, and I think yours should really be the accepted answer. I would delete my answer to enforce it but I still think it adds something to the question. Re: Using column ordinals, again I agree, but the question states they want to *define the first column as the primary key.*. Using column ordinals was the only way I could think of to define first.

Comment: You're right @TimSchmelter but yea I'me trying to define the first column as the primary one so this is the most fitting answer for my question but still your's also good I will use it for the 2 other databse I need to fill thank

Answer (score 10):

You have to set the `DataAdapter`'s [`MissingSchemaAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.missingschemaaction.aspx) to `AddWithKey`:

```
var table = new DataTable();
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Articles", con))
{
    da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
    da.Fill(table);
}
```

**Edit**: VB.NET:

```
Dim table = New DataTable()
Using con = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Using da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Articles", con)
        da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
        da.Fill(table)
    End Using
End Using
```

Now the necessary columns and primary key information to complete the schema are automaticaly added to the `DataTable`.

Read: [Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bh8kx08z.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please do it like this.

```
Dim objTmpTable As New DataTable
   objTmpTable.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {objTmpTable.Columns(0)}
   dgrdMeasure.DataSource = objTmpTable
   dgrdMeasure.DataBind()
```

That is, before assigning to Grid, just set the Primary key.